# Why databound ContextMenu items don't hide?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, contextmenu, menuitem

I wan't to hide/show menuitems in a contextmenu using some propery of databound object.
But my menuitems don't hide, they behave as if their Visiblity would be set to Visibility.Hidden (not Visibility.Collapsed as it really is), what's the reason of such behaviour?

Here's an example:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MenuTest.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="converter"/>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="template">            
            <MenuItem Visibility="{Binding Visible, Converter={StaticResource converter}}" Header="{Binding Title}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="menu" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource template}"/>                    
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="OnClick">Button</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And code behind:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Item> list = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            list.Add(new Item() { Title = "First", Visible = true }); ;
            list.Add(new Item() { Title = "Second", Visible = false }); ;
            list.Add(new Item() { Title = "Third", Visible = false }); ;
            list.Add(new Item() { Title = "Fourth", Visible = true }); ;
        }

        private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ContextMenu cm =  FindResource("menu") as ContextMenu;
            cm.PlacementTarget = e.OriginalSource as UIElement;
            cm.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Left;
            cm.ItemsSource = list;
            cm.IsOpen = true;
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public bool Visible { get; set; }
    }
```

The result is menu with four items (but two in the middle without any visible text in header).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is because the ItemTemplate of ContextMenu will be applied to each of your bound Items *within* the MenuItem created for that Item.  By putting a MenuItem into your DataTemplate, you create a nested MenuItem.  Even if you collapse the inner one, since the outer one is still visible, there is still space for it.

You can fix this by getting rid of the nested MenuItem in your DataTemplate and replacing it with a TextBlock, and using a Style that applies to MenuItem to set the Visibility:

```
<Window x:Class="MenuTest.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="converter"/>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="template">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="menu" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource template}">
            <ContextMenu.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Visible, Converter={StaticResource converter}}"/>
                </Style>
            </ContextMenu.Resources>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="OnClick">Button</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Wow, that was quick. Thanks. I thought I've checked it in Snoop, but apparently I was wrong. ;)